# Get a Message Box text in Run Time in vba application

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using Office 2007 and working on vba application in access 2007. I need to get the text of message box or error message which appears in run time displaying the message with either vbOK or vbYes/vbNo options. Please if anyone can help me how can i get the text of that pop up box in RunTime.

Comment: To learn on MessageBox, Check this URL: http://analysistabs.com/vba/msgbox-examples-macros/

Comment: thank u..i have gone through the link u provided.but i was not able to find the solution of problem i had above. i need to get text of msgbox "the text which appears in Message Box"

Comment: Which text you want? Basically we set the text in message box. Error message are system generated pop up and yes we can get the text of error messages.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you out? http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tips-for-handling-errors-in-vba/

Answer (score 1):

If you error trap properly, all you need is

```
Err.Description
```

That's exactly what shows up in error messageboxes.